# Proactive MutationObserver - intercept node before adding to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, mutation-observers

I need to intercept  nodes ***before*** they are placed in the DOM to manipulate attributes (src + sandbox).
I use youtube embeds on my site and due to GDPR and data-protection-rights, I ***need*** to intercept the placement of cookies from those iframes. I've tested lots of ideas, but my big issue is that all attempts execute ***after*** the iframes were already inserted into the DOM.

My current, best attempt is:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    [].filter
      .call(mutation.addedNodes, function (node) {
        return node.nodeName == 'IFRAME';
      })
      .forEach(function (node) {
        node.setAttribute('data-src', node.getAttribute('src'));
        node.setAttribute('sandbox', '');
        node.setAttribute('src', '');
      });
  });
});
observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome the iframes execute their requests and place cookies before the attributes are altered.
I've learned that MutationObserver are strictly reactive, so in theory my attempt shouldn't even work in Firefox.

What can I do to block iframes from loading and placing cookies?

Any help/ideas are happily welcomed!

Comment: In theory... that's a bit of an undefined behavior... The loading of the iframe content should be done "in parallel", and the MutationEvent should fire in a micro-task right after the task that did the mutation. So...FF's behavior seems a bit more logical, but it is "in theory" possible that the iframe did load its content while the task was still running... Though from experience, Chrome likes to run this things synchronously if it can. But to your problem now, who is responsible for the insertion of these nodes? That's where you need to hook.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you for the needed insight! I've noticed in person that Chrome uses async wherever possible, when using the debugger it works just like in FF. Without breakpoints however it does not. Well - the iframes are part of the site's html, they are inserted with the initial page load, so I'm not sure what specifically is responsible.

Comment: "the iframes are part of the site's html" -> The web dev that did write that markup is the responsible ;-) So the easy solution: edit that markup to what you want it to be directly. i.e instead of `<iframe src="https://evil-site.com"></iframe>`, directly make the HTML markup be `<iframe data-src="https://evil-site.com"></iframe>`.

Comment: Nice one :) the dev probably feels guilty for the pain that iframes have brought upon humanity. I would like to do that  however, we use a cms and users can place video embeds in articles. I cant access how those iframe attributes are initially set, so I need to alter them on page load, but before the browser executes them.

Comment: You could try to search synchronously at the bottom of the page, `<script>document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(el =>...)` but I doubt it would change anything, or if it does, it will probably not *always* do... Can't your CMS do some preprocessing replacing `/src=/` to `"data-src="?

Comment: Any attempt from the bottom of the body wont help me, I'm afraid. I will look into your suggestion, my hopes are slim.. the client uses webflow and can't be convinced to migrate to anything more capable. I've had to invent so many workarounds already. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You can block iframes using Content-Security-Policy. It can be set via a `<meta>` element or as an HTTP header so you'll have to set it on the server and reload the page if you want to toggle the behavior.

Comment: Thank you! Was a new approach, unfortunately I dont have access to the server and have to rely on the meta tag. Works like a charm for blocking them! That's BIG :) Sadly I need to be able to override the CSP after the user consented. Altering the meta tag wont work due to the policy only being applied once one initial load.

Comment: You can probably use a `nonce` in CSP and its value in the `nonce` attribute on iframes after consent. I haven't tried this so look for more info.